# Why patching a string using .ptr fails under Linux64 but not under Win32?

Tags: string, pointers, portability, d

Why the small sample below fails under Linux64 but not under Windows32?

```
module test;

import std.string, std.stdio;

void main(string[] args)
{
    string a = "abcd=1234";
    auto b = &a;
    auto Index = indexOf(*b, '=');

    if (Index != -1)
        *cast (char*) (b.ptr + Index) = '#';

    writeln(*b);
    readln;
}
```

Comment: if it fails under one but not under the other I suspect UD

Comment: you meant UB I guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

one thing to remember is that `string` is an alias to `(immutable char)[]` which means that trying to write to the elements is undefined behavior

one of the reasons that I can think the behavior differs is that under linux64 the compiler puts the string data in write-protected memory, which means that `*cast (char*) (b.ptr + Index) = '#';` fails (either silently or with segfault)

Comment: This. Actually, same behavior difference exists also for C/C++ between Linux and Windows, if you try to mutate string literal. There can never be a legitimate reason to mutate a string in D and it is typical Undefined Behavior.

Comment: I was also thinking about the immutability of strings, as an explaination of the issue (btw it's a seg fault at run-time), and the purpose of the Q was to get the mind from expert people... but don't you think that it's quite paradoxical that the 'immutability' is relative under Win and absolute under Linux ?! It should be absolutely immutable on both systems! An this also explains another issue I encounter in another context. Awesome.

Comment: it just means that win doesn't provide read only memory blocks for code (where string literals are generally stored)

Comment: There is no "absolute immutability". Immutable is just a compile time type annotation in D, there is no way to know what will happen at runtime if you ignore the compile time checks. string.ptr returns immutable(char)* and the compiler guarantees at compile time that you can't modify the data pointed to by this pointer. If you cast to char* then it's absolutely undefined what will happen at runtime. Although a language could provide additional runtime checks D does not for performance reasons. The segfault on linux is only a linux-specific safety net we get for free.